# What are the performance issues which are involved if ids in the naming container of the jsff page in ADF exceed seven characters in length?

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

I have created an ADF web application in which the table component has more than seven characters in its ID attribute.
I am receiving a warning that for better performance the ID should be less than 7 characters. 
However I am not receiving the same warning for other components.

I couldn't find sufficient documentation which addresses this problem.
How can the ID attribute impact the performance of my application if there are 40k concurrent requests set for the benchmark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The longer the id, the longer the generated HTML will be. That's it.